# BackAndroid hardwareBackPress listener stops working after returning to initial route

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React Native app that is on 0.18, and am trying to implement back button functionality for Android. I have the following code in my `index.android.js`:

```
let navigator;

BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
  if (navigator && navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
    navigator.pop();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

And in my render:

```
<Navigator
    ref={(nav) => { navigator = nav; }}
    ...
```

The back button works if I go forward any number of routes, and I can then go back any number of routes to the initial route. However, after going back to the initial route, the back button stops working until I reload JS or otherwise restart the app.

Has anyone else encountered this and what is the solution?

Edit: I've tested on 0.21, 0.22, and 0.23-rc3 and am still having this issue in the latest release.

Comment: I have very similar piece of code and with that code, back button exits the whole app when on initial route. This was the purpose, right?

Comment: Somewhat. If I start up the app, then immediately click the back button, it does exit the app. However, if I start the app, go forward to any route, then click the back button, clicking the back button again will not exit the app, and if I go forward to another route again, clicking the back button will not take me back to the initial route as it should either.

Comment: Essentially it's as if the listener stops listening after I go back to the initial route. If I put a console.log in the handler, it doesn't get fired upon clicking back after navigating back to the initial route either.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was that, in other components of the app, we had added event handlers to handle changing layouts on opening the keyboard, and on unmounting these components, we were calling `DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners()`. Contrary to intuition, this call removes all listeners globally, regardless of the instantiating component, and applies even to listeners instantiated on `BackAndroid` instead of on `DeviceEventEmitter`. So, after going back from a component that had a keyboard-toggled layout, the `hardwareBackPress` listener was also removed and the back button stopped working.

Making the `removeAllListeners` calls more specific e.g. `DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners('keyboardWillShow');` resolved this issue.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem as OP, but I'm not using any `DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners()` in my code. What else could cause this behaviour?